# How to make a paragraph in Hugo?

Tags: html, css, hugo, toml

I've built a website with Hugo. In the config.toml, there are a few lines as below:

```
[params]
    name = "My name"
    description = "Blog Description"
    bio = "Data Analyst at [@X](https://www.x.com/)"
```

Now, I'd like to add one more to my blog in bio like this:

```
[params]
    name = "My name"
    description = "Blog Description"
    bio = "Data Analyst at [@X](https://www.x.com/)" 
    "previously at [@Y](https://www.y.com/)"
```

However, it does not come out. What am I making wrong here? HTML code with p did not work as well.

Comment: `[params]` is not directly used by Hugo, but is given meaning by the theme. What theme are you using?

Comment: thanks for your comment. @Smitop I am using this: https://github.com/ribbybibby/hugo-theme-cactus-plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bio = "Data Analyst at [@X](https://www.x.com/) <br /> previously at [@Y](https://www.y.com/)"
```

if the `<br />` or `<p>` or whatever you decide to put there renders as `"<br..."` etc. Then wherever site.Params.bio or .Site.Params.bio is (in the layouts etc), add
"| safeHTML" i.e. {{ .site.Params.bio | safeHTML }}

Or just ask the theme maintainer to add whatever you want.

Note: You could just add a new bit in whatever template you wish to output this,
example

```
bio = "Data Analyst at [@X](https://www.x.com/)"   
more_bio = "previously at [@Y](https://www.y.com/)"
```

{{ .Site.Params.more_bio }} <- put that wherever you want it to output (in whatever layout)

Etc...

https://gohugo.io/variables/site/